# Como sincronizar o Github com o npm

Tags: github, npm

Existe alguma forma de atualizar o ***package*** no ***npm*** conforme vou mandando atualizações para a branch master do meu repositório?

Comment: Você pode usar GitHub Actions. Circle CI também é uma opção. Qualquer ferramenta de CI, na verdade... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você precisa é um processo de build automatizdo, ou CI, integração contínua de código, esse processo é responsável por compilação ou transpilação, no caso de javascript, rodar testes e empacotar o artefato em um pacote npm, por exemplo!

Existem várias aplicações de integração contínua ([continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)) ou build:

- [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_(software))
- [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/)
- [Azure DevOps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops)
- [Github Actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions)

  Se o seu repositório está no Github, usar o Github Action talvez faça mais sentido do que qualquer um outro.

Pode parecer trabalhoso mas com o tempo você irá perceber o valor de ter um pipeline automatizado, vai garantir que você não quebre um pacote por esquecer algo, já que o processo pode te dar algumas garantias; além é claro de a automação poupar um trabalho considerável de toda vez ter que gerar o pacote e fazer upload.